# How to check if a tensor is present in another tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What I want to do is check if the tensor **t1 = [[[1. , 2. , 3.4]]]** is present in another tensor **t2 = [[[1. , 5. , 3.4], [1. , 2. , 3.4]]]**. I tried using tf.equal() for this but it returns this

```
tf.equal(t2, t1) # Output : [[[True False True] [True True True]]]
```

What I want is a single bool value (True or False) telling whether **t1** is present in **t2** or not.
Something like

```
if your_method(t2, t1):
  print("Yes, t1 is contained in t2.")
```

Is there a **completely pythonic** way to do this?
Also, I checked it, tf.listdiff() is not supported anymore.

**Edit:**

Ok, I found a [tf.math.reduce_all()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_all) method which can be applied to the above output tensor of

```
[[[True False True] [True True True]]]
```

to reduce it to a tensor like

`[[[True False True]]]`

But I still don't know how to obtain the correct answer (which would be a single bool value of True) out of this.
Also if I apply [tf.math.reduce_any()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_any) to

`[[[True False True] [True True True]]]`

it can be reduced to

`[[[True True True]]]`

(again giving me a tensor and not a single bool value) and then if I assume that the answer will be True as all the elements of the resultant tensor are True then this won't be correct as tf.math.reduce_all() also gives a similar result for the case when tf.equal()'s output would have been

`[[[True False True] [False True False]]]`

that is, if for example **t1 = [[[1., 2., 3.4]]]** and **t2 = [[[1., 5., 3.4], [6., 2., 7.8]]]**.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the `in` operator work here by any chance?

Comment: In numpy, you could use the result of equal thusly: `np.any(np.all(np.equal(t2, t1), axis=1))`. I'd expect tf to have an analogous set of operations

Comment: @MadPhysicist , no the `in` operator is returning false

Comment: I don't think you need to transform anything into numpy. I'm not super familiar with tf, but I'm guessing that it'll have any and all methods

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I just checked, there aren't any tf.any() or tf.all() methods, they have a tf.reduce_any() method which performs 'logical or' operation across the dimensions of a tensor containing boolean values though.

Comment: That's exactly what you're looking for. Also, I'd expect the methods to be part of the tensor class, not necessarily the tf module itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options you have.

1. Using numpy

First evaluate the tensors to get numpy arrays for respective tensors and use `in` operator.

```
t1_array = t1.eval()
t2_array = t2.eval()
t1_array in t2_array # this will be true if t2 contians t1.
```

2. Using tensorflow [equal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/equal), [reduce_any](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_any) and [reduce_all](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_all) methods.

```
# check equality of array in t1 for each array in t2 element by element. This is possible because the equal function supports broadcasting. 
equal =  tf.math.equal(t1, t2)
# checking if all elements from  t1 match for all elements of some array in t2
equal_all = tf.reduce_all(equal, axis=2)
contains = tf.reduce_any(equal_all)
```

#### Edit

If eager execution is enabled

```py
contains = t1.numpy() in t2.numpy() # this will be true if t2 contians t1.
```

Comment: Note that the `axis=2` in `reduce_all` assumes a particular shape for the tensors you're comparing e.g. (n, m) vs (m, n) will require different axes. The axis in this answer is specific to the Tensors in the question

Comment: The `in` operator in numpy doesn't do what you would expect. For instance `np.array([[[1., 2., 3.4]]]) in np.array([[[1., 3., 100.]]])` returns `True`